# How to restore a certificate from a backup

Tags: backup, virtual-machines, ssl-certificate, restore

I have an authenticode certificate living in a backup created with Drive Snapshot, which is a byte level backup of the c: partition from my development machine.

I need to export that certificate.

I have converted that backup to a vmdk file and tried to boot windows 7, but I get a blue screen which I feel has something to do with the virtual disk controller drivers. Anyway....

Is there any way to export a certificate or use certmgr from the command line, because I can get to a command prompt using a windows 7 disk. I just can't boot into windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can [download](http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/diskmount_ws_v55.html) a tool from VMWare to mount a VMDK directly as a drive without the need to boot the system.

Edit: I believe that DriveSnapshot is able to do this all by itself without prior conversion to an VMDK file.

Comment: My questions wasn't how to mount a backup. I need to export a certificate from the backup of windows 7.